# Set value of one record in a group based on conditions - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Documents` that contains URLs for documents (drawings) stored on our server for each item that is on our system.

There is a field called `PrintAsThumbnail` that is a `bit` field and this tells the system whether to put the image onto some documentation. We may have multiple documents stored against a single part. If more than one document has this `PrintAsThumbnail` ticked, it goes into meltdown and prints nothing.

What I want to do is write some script that ticks ONE box PER item based on the following priorities;

1. If `documentGroupFK` = 1 then this is the one that is ticked for the item regardless.
2. Otherwise, if the URL contains `%.dxf%` then this is the one ticked
3. Otherwise, if the image is an image file (generally `.png` or `jpg` or `bmp`) then any of these can be the one that is ticked
4. Otherwise, don't tick any as chances are, the rest would be a `pdf` and they don't display anyway.

I have approximately 12900 different items and around 15000 records.

I've googled UPDATE or SELECT 1 record per item and that has pointed me to the code below (credit @gbn on this site) but I'm struggling to adapt it to get me what I need.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemFK ORDER BY DocumentPK DESC) AS rn
   FROM Document where SUM(PrintAsThumbnail) > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

My expectations are for each item (`itemFK`) to have a maximum of ONE `PrintAsThumbnail` ticked based on the rules above so that the most relevant part appears on our documentation. I would run this script periodically to ensure the system is up to date.

Sample Data as is now

```
+--------+-----------------+-------+------------------+
| ItemFK | DocumentGroupFK |  URL  | PrintAsThumbnail |
+--------+-----------------+-------+------------------+
|      1 |               0 | %.dxf |                0 |
|      1 |               0 | %.pdf |                0 |
|      2 |               1 | %.jpg |                1 |
|      2 |               0 | %.pdf |                1 |
|      2 |               0 | %.dxf |                1 |
|      3 |               1 | %.dxf |                0 |
|      3 |               0 | %.pdf |                1 |
|      3 |               0 | %.bmp |                1 |
|        |                 |       |                  |
+--------+-----------------+-------+------------------+
```

Sample Data after running update script

```
+--------+-----------------+-------+------------------+
| ItemFK | DocumentGroupFK |  URL  | PrintAsThumbnail |
+--------+-----------------+-------+------------------+
|      1 |               0 | %.dxf |                1 |
|      1 |               0 | %.pdf |                0 |
|      2 |               1 | %.jpg |                1 |
|      2 |               0 | %.pdf |                0 |
|      2 |               0 | %.dxf |                0 |
|      3 |               1 | %.dxf |                1 |
|      3 |               0 | %.pdf |                0 |
|      3 |               0 | %.bmp |                0 |
|        |                 |       |                  |
+--------+-----------------+-------+------------------+
```

Notice that all items just have ONE `printAsThumbnail` ticked. 
Item 1 has a `pdf` & a `.dxf`, so the rules dictate it being the `.dxf` that is ticked. 
Item 2 has `pdf`, an image and a `dxf`, but the priority 1 rule is that if it has a `documentGroupFK` of 1, then that is the one that is ticked.
Item 3 has the same as 2, but no `documentGroupFK` assigned, so the rules state that the `.dxf` is chosen as the one ticked.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @jarlh I've added some sample data ... but it's formatted horrifically. I used an online web app to create the table. Can anyone help format it properly please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the logic, I would expect the logic to look like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT d.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemFK 
                                ORDER BY documentGroupFK DESC,
                                         (CASE WHEN url LIKE '%.dxf%' THEN 1
                                               WHEN url LIKE '%.png' OR URL LIKE '%.jpg'
                               ) AS rn
      FROM Document where SUM(PrintAsThumbnail) > 1
     )
UPDATE cte
    SET PrintAsThumbnail = (CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND
                                      (documentGroupFK = 1 OR
                                       url LIKE '%.dxf%' OR
                                       url LIKE '%.png%' OR
                                       url LIKE '%.jpg%'
                                      )
                                 THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END);
```

Note that this sets both `1` and `0` values, to ensure that there are not duplicates.

Comment: Before I run it, does this set the printAsThumbnail based on the documentGroupFK being 1 (the first priority)? I can't see any reference to DocumentGroupFK in the code. Have you put it as DocumentPK instead (I do have a document PK but this is different to the group). Apologies if I've misunderstood and thanks for this.

Comment: @David . . . It is `documentGroupFK`.